# Why can I not uninstall dnsmasq with brew?

Tags: homebrew, dnsmasq

I am on Mac OS Ventura.  `brew list` shows that dnsmasq is installed.

Here's the commands I am running:

```
sudo brew services stop dnsmasq
rm -f /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
sudo rm -rf /etc/resolver
brew uninstall --force dnsmasq
```

Outputs

- line 1: Warning: Service `dnsmasq` is not started
- line 2: (no output)
- line 3: (no output)
- line 4: (no output)

But brew list shows that `dnsmasq` is still installed.